# Select the Data of a Column of an interactive report in Apex

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I want to SELECT a cretain column of an interactive report when a button is clicked. When the button is clicked, it needs to get forwarded to another page. I do not want to re-run the Query, since it is quiet time consuming to run.

Is there any way to query the interactive report with plsql/javascript or save it and forward the queried data when the user clicks the button?

Comment: Are you talking about perhaps using target=_blank to retain your original IR results? If so, instead you could populate an APEX collection, then base your IR on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interactive report has an option to include the link column (an icon at the beginning of each row). You can set it to navigate to virtually anywhere you want; usual option is to navigate to another page in this application. Also, you can set parameters' values which are then transferred onto the target page, into its items.

Or, you can create your own link column. The oldfashioned way is to do it HTML-way (using `<a href=...>` syntax) or using `APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL` procedure (which would be the preferred way).

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I just noticed that I wrote Row, while I intended to write Column. Sorry for the inconvinience, I edited the question

Comment: Why don't you then click the column (which is a link) directly, instead of clicking some button which is - how? Automagically? - supposed to select a column (?) and navigate to another page?